# antd ConfigProvider set prefixCls not in full effect coming from different packages

Tags: reactjs, antd, monorepo, pnpm

There is antdV4 version in the multi-package project, and now we want to use antdv5. In order to ensure      that the style is not affected, prefix is set at the entrance of the new package. However, this package refers to components wrapped by other packages, where the antd component prefix is not set。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Huo.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Ksf.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMC4W.png)  Hopefully, the prefix will be set successfully, regardless of which package it was imported from

Comment: Welcome! Your images seem to have annotations in chinese. Can you please [edit] to use English? [Posts on Stack Exchange must be in English](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/997587). See also: [We require English on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/11107541).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.